# Decision tree - multiple instances

Tags: r, tree, dataframe, decision-tree

Starting from these data

```
i <- c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")
g <- c("man","man","woman","man","woman","man","woman","man")
r <- c("100","34","22","42","62","73","8","66")
o <- c("A1","A2","A3","A2","A2","A1","A3","A2")

data <- data.frame (i,g,r,o)
```

I need to build a decision tree in order to identify rules for every instance of the column "o" like that

```
if i=1 and g=man and r=100 then A1
```

Could someone suggest which R algorithm I have to use?

Comment: You can search for `?rpart` from `library(rpart)`.  Installing `rattle` would make it easier though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are implying that o is your outcome.

```
require(rpart)
fit <- rpart(o ~ i + g + r, dta)
plot(fit) # won't work as not a tree (too little data)
text(fit)
```

Comment: Perfect! Basically everybody see this algorithm as part of a prediction step. But according to my understanding it is just data mining. Can I say that if a use a new row of my dataset and I apply the fit to my new rows this is a prediction ?

Comment: Moreover supposing my dataset will ne enriched by 10 rows every day. For how many days can I use the fit model to provide prediction? Are there some way to test  that fit model is not anymore adeguate to the data?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a prediction if you are applying your fit to predict values for new data? The second question is not straightforward. Especially as I really know nothing about your day. My suggestion would be to cross-validate your model which may help give a better indication of how your model will perform out-of-sample. The `caret` package is great for this as well as tuning model parameters, please see the following page for more detail: http://topepo.github.io/caret/

Comment: I have opehretned a new thread to better explain my doubt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253566/prediction-r-evaluation-before-to-apply